# How to add a close button to an image that opens from a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of thumbnail images into a hrefs that link to the full size image. I would like to add a close button to the full size image. I was thinking of using an iframe for that. Would that do or can you think of another way of doing that?

Thanks a lot!

HTML

```
<div class="finishing-touches-contempovertical">
    <a id="thumb" class="thumb1" href="images/image.jpg">
      <img src="images/image-thumbnail.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a.thumb1 {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: 20px 10px 10px 660px;
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zPQ7U/

Comment: How are you currently showing the full size images?

Comment: Yes. But where do you go if you click on it? Does it show in a popup window, in a new window?

Comment: How you are showing those images? using jQuery plugin? Code please

Comment: If I click on it the image opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use popup and jquery

```
<style>
#popup{
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
/* your styles */
}
</style>

<div class="finishing-touches-contempovertical">
  <a id="thumb" class="thumb1" href="images/image.jpg">
    <img src="images/image-thumbnail.jpg"/>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="close_popup">X</div>
</div>

<script>
$('a.thumb1').on('click',function(){ // when press link

   var fullImg = $(this).attr('href') // get full size img url
   $('#popup img').attr('src', fullImg) // image in popup now has source that you need
   $('#popup').show() // popup appears
   return false // do not redirect 

})

$('.close_popup').on('click', function(){

   $('#popup').hide() // close popup

})
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ha5fH/1/